# Bring Powershell-Console to front from WinForms

Tags: windows, forms, powershell, user-interface, console

im trying to bring my powershell console to front, even if it is minimized.
I found following code:

```
function Show-Process($Process, [Switch]$Maximize)
{
  $sig = '
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);
  '

  if ($Maximize) { $Mode = 3 } else { $Mode = 4 }
  $type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -Name WindowAPI -PassThru
  $hwnd = $process.MainWindowHandle
  $null = $type::ShowWindowAsync($hwnd, $Mode)
  $null = $type::SetForegroundWindow($hwnd) 
}
Show-Process -Process (Get-Process -Id $pid)
```

It works fine, but when i call the function from a Button Click event, the console wont show.
What is the Problem? Is there a way to bring the powershell Console to front when using a WinForms GUI?

Here is the example GUI Code:

```
function Show-Process($Process, [Switch]$Maximize)
{
  $sig = '
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);
  '

  if ($Maximize) { $Mode = 3 } else { $Mode = 4 }
  $type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -Name WindowAPI -PassThru
  $hwnd = $process.MainWindowHandle
  $null = $type::ShowWindowAsync($hwnd, $Mode)
  $null = $type::SetForegroundWindow($hwnd) 
}

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = '446,266'
$Form.text                       = "Form"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false

$Button1                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.text                    = "button"
$Button1.width                   = 60
$Button1.height                  = 30
$Button1.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,29)
$Button1.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Button1.Add_Click({
    Show-Process -Process (Get-Process -Id $pid) 
})

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Button1))

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: can you show the click event and form

Comment: @ArcSet edited the code

Comment: How is `$pid` set?

Comment: $pid is always the PID of your PS-Process.
You don't have to set it.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @iRon's answer, i was able to figure it out, how i want it.
For anyone curious, the problem is, you only can get the consoles MainwindowHandle as long as ShowDialog wasn't called.
So i save the console Handle in a variable and i use the Form_Shown event to get the Form WindowHandle, since Form_Load still returns the Console Handle.

```
$sig = '
[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);'
$type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -Name WindowAPI -PassThru
[IntPtr]$handleConsole = (Get-Process -Id $pid).MainWindowHandle
[void]$type::ShowWindowAsync($handleConsole, 4);[void]$type::SetForegroundWindow($handleConsole)

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = '446,266'
$Form.text                       = "Form"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false

$Form.Add_Shown({
 $global:handleForm = (Get-Process -Id $pid).MainWindowHandle
})

$Button1                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.text                    = "Clone ad-USer"
$Button1.width                   = 60
$Button1.height                  = 30
$Button1.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,29)
$Button1.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Button1.Add_Click({
    [void]$type::ShowWindowAsync($handleConsole, 4);[void]$type::SetForegroundWindow($handleConsole)
    Read-Host -Prompt "Please Enter a Value"
    [void]$type::ShowWindowAsync($global:handleForm, 4);[void]$type::SetForegroundWindow($global:handleForm)
})

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Button1))

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Now, if i press the Button, to console pops up in front.
After the User enter something into the Console, the Form comes to front again.

Comment: As an aside: It's better to use `$script:`-scoped variables, because global variables linger after your script exits.
In this case, however, you don't need to set a variable in an ancestral scope at all: just use `$Form.Handle` in your button-click event handler or, in a more encapsulated fashion: `$this.FindForm().Handle`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I can't completely fix it, but maybe others might help you further based on my findings:

First of all, the process within the button click event is a different process space as where the parent PowerShell host runs in. This can be easily proven but revealing the `$hwhd` with `Write-Host $hwnd` in the `Show-Process` function and also calling the `Show-Process` function prior calling the `ShowDialog`:

```
Show-Process -Process (Get-Process -Id $pid) 
[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

In other words: to fix this part, you will need to the catch the parent `$Pid` from the PowerShell window first:

```
$Button1.Add_Click({
    Show-Process -Process $MyProcess 
})

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Button1))

$MyProcess = Get-Process -Id $pid
Show-Process -Process $MyProcess
[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

The above snippet works, but as soon I remove (or comment out) the line `Show-Process -Process $MyProcess` (at the host level), it breaks again...

Comment: Everything runs in the same process. The reason that `.MainWindowHandle` changes is that by design it reports the handle of the window that currently has the focus - originally, that is the console window; while the form is being displayed, it is the form. The reason that caching the _process_ object works is that `.MainWindowHandle` isn't dynamically updated - you have to call `.Refresh()` manually.

Answer (score 2):

As you've discovered, [`.MainWindowHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_MainWindowHandle) is not a *static* property (from the linked docs; emphasis added):

> The main window is the window opened by the process that *currently has the focus* [...]

Therefore, what the value of the current process' `.MainWindowHandle` property changes from the *console-window* handle to the *WinForms window* while the form is being displayed.<sup>[1]</sup>

Caching the console-window handle *before* you display the form is definitely an option, but there's an easier way, given that you're already using `Add-Member` with WinAPI P/Invoke declarations: The [`GetConsoleWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolewindow)  WinAPI function *always* returns the current process' console-window handle.

Additionally, your `$Forms` form instance has a `.Handle` property, which directly returns the form's window handle - no `(Get-Process -Id $pid).MainWindowHandle` call needed.

The following solution therefore needs no global or script-level variables and confines querying the window handles to the button-click event handler:

```
# P/Invoke signatures - note the addition of GetConsoleWindow():
$sig = '
[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();'

$type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -Name WindowAPI -PassThru

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{
  ClientSize = '446,266'
  text = "Form"
}

$Button1 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button -Property @{
  text = "Test"
  location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75, 29)
}

$Button1.Add_Click({
    # Get this form's window handle.
    $handleForm = $Form.Handle # More generically: $this.FindForm().Handle
    # Get the console window's handle.
    $handleConsole = $type::GetConsoleWindow()
    # Activate the console window and prompt the user.
    $null = $type::ShowWindowAsync($handleConsole, 4); $null = $type::SetForegroundWindow($handleConsole)
    Read-Host -Prompt "Please Enter a Value"
    # Reactivate this form.
    $null = $type::ShowWindowAsync($handleForm, 4); $null = $type::SetForegroundWindow($handleForm)
  })

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Button1))

$null = $Form.ShowDialog()
```

---

<sup>[1] Note that a *cached* process object doesn't dynamically update its `.MainWindowHandle` value; you have to call `.Refresh()` manually. 
 Because [iRon's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53130006/45375) caches the current-process object *before* displaying the form, it still happens to reflect the console-window handle inside the button-click handler.</sup>